# Download torrent content without Monotorrent

Tags: c#, .net, bittorrent, torrent, monotorrent

I am absolutely novice about the Bittorrent protocol and I want to know if it is possible to download the files from a .torrent file using the Bittorrent protocol with C#.NET but without Monotorrent (not updated since 4 years and i don't want to depends on a tier-party).

If it is possible, what may be the best way to do it ?
Thank you !

Comment: This might help http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19172/c-up-to-date-torrent-library

Comment: https://github.com/rakshasa/libtorrent is the way to go. maybe with an internal wrapper or an existing one

Comment: Ragnar seems not optimized, after 30secs it takes 2Go on my memory and makes the program crash... :/
I'll explore the sockets way